# Efficient way of storing 1TB of random data with Zarr

Tags: numpy, zarr

I'd like to store 1TB of random data backed by a zarr on disk array.  Currently, I am doing something like the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import zarr
from numcodecs import Blosc

compressor = Blosc(cname='lz4', clevel=5, shuffle=Blosc.BITSHUFFLE)
store = zarr.DirectoryStore('TB1.zarr')
root = zarr.group(store)
TB1 = root.zeros('data',
           shape=(1_000_000, 1_000_000),
           chunks=(20_000, 5_000),
           compressor=compressor,
           dtype='|i2')

for i in range(1_000_000): 
    TB1[i, :1_000_000] = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=1_000_000, dtype='|i2')
```

This is going to take some time -- I know things could probably be improved if I wasn't always generating `1_000_000` random numbers and instead reusing the array but I'd like some more randomness for now. Is there a better way to go about building this random dataset ?

### Update 1

Using bigger numpy blocks speeds things up a bit:

```py
for i in range(0, 1_000_000, 100_000): 
    TB1[i:i+100_000, :1_000_000] = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(100_000, 1_000_000), dtype='|i2')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Dask Array](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array.html) which will enable parallel computation of random numbers and storage, e.g.:

```py
import zarr                                                           
from numcodecs import Blosc                                           
import dask.array as da                                               

shape = 1_000_000, 1_000_000                                          
dtype = 'i2'                                                          
chunks = 20_000, 5_000                                                
compressor = Blosc(cname='lz4', clevel=5, shuffle=Blosc.BITSHUFFLE) 

# set up zarr array to store data
store = zarr.DirectoryStore('TB1.zarr')
root = zarr.group(store) 
TB1 = root.zeros('data', 
                 shape=shape, 
                 chunks=chunks, 
                 compressor=compressor, 
                 dtype=dtype) 

# set up a dask array with random numbers
d = da.random.randint(0, 3, size=shape, dtype=dtype, chunks=chunks)  

# compute and store the random numbers
d.store(TB1, lock=False)
```

By default Dask will compute using all available local cores, but can also be configured to run on a cluster via the [Distributed](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/) package.